# What do i have to include to know if this is a user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Every new page someone opens, I would like to know if he is a signed in user.

I do this with  (is it wrong? maybe Firebase will not be ready?):

```
if(firebase.auth().currentUser)
```

if this is a user, i only want to ***write*** something to database.
But I have a feeling , i am including too many things for this purpose.

So i have to initiate the app for sure :

```
 <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
  <script>
       var config = {
         apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
         databaseURL: "https://xx.firebaseio.com",
         projectId: "xx",
         storageBucket: "xx.appspot.com",
         messagingSenderId: "xxx"
       };
       firebase.initializeApp(config);
       const db = firebase.firestore();
  </script>
```

Then, which of these is ***not*** necessary ?

```
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in realtime for user auth changes, and perform operations (change a global variable, state variable, update database values, etc) with it, you only need firebase-app & firebase-auth, firebase-firestore is optional as you can write data in your api/server (firebase-admin) or with an http request:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Be careful to have database rules to take care of your database writings

EDIT: this is an example of how to add data without firestore library:

```
const data = {
  fields: {
    name: { stringValue: 'Joe' },
    email: { stringValue: 'joe@mail.com' },
    message: { stringValue: 'Hello' },
    phone: { stringValue: '123456' },
    modified: { timestampValue: new Date() },
  },
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOURDB/databases/(default)/documents/clients/someclient/contact',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success() {
    console.log('Document successfully written!');
    return true;
  },
  error(err) {
    console.error('Error saving document', err);
    return false;
  },
})
```

Comment: Wait so to do  :   firebase.firestore().collection(collection).doc(doc).set  -   i dont need firebase-firestore ?

Comment: In that way you do need firestore but if you want something more simple, like just a contact form, there's no need to import a >100kb library, just make an http request, let me show you, answer edited

Answer (score 1):

for using `firebase.auth()` you need only `firebase-app` and `firebase-auth` but i can see that you are also using the database so you will need `firebase-firestore` too

Comment: Thanks, but if i check firebase.auth().currentUser right after init, will it be ready to show if its a user ?

Comment: @hkrly yes it will return the user object if he is logged in